# wordpress plugin wp_editor doesn't post images

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin with a visual editor and add media button that can POST and insert into the database all the HTML data. Here is my code:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
   print_r($_POST);
   global $wpdb;
   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "eventi_ecm"; 
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $text = $_POST['content'];
   //$rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'time' => current_time('mysql'), 'name' => $name, 'text' => $text ) );
 }
 $settings = array('textarea_name' => 'content','media_buttons' => true,'tinymce' => false);
?>
<div>
    <h2>New Event</h2>
    <form method="post" action="http://test.ble-group.com/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=eventi_new_page">
        <div id="poststuff">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <?php wp_editor( '', 'content', $settings ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
        <p><input type="submit"/></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

But when I try to insert images, the HTML code about the image it's stripped. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks @user850010, but didn't worked, I solved this way:

```
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( stripslashes($_POST['content']) ) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://aerin.co.uk/how-to-stop-the-wp_editor-from-removing-formatting/) article which might help you.

In short, article suggests to use this code:

```
<?php wp_editor( stripslashes($content), $editor-id ); ?>
```

and this code to display the output:

```
<?php echo wpautop(stripslashes($editor-id)); ?>
```